# Reactive adding/removing inputs with Reagent-forms

Tags: user-input, clojurescript, reagent, reagent-forms

I have some datastructure in an atom I want to bind to inputs using reagent-forms. The tricky thing is, that I want to bind not only the content of the inputs to said atom, but the inputs themselves; i.e. I want to reactively remove and add input fields by manipulating the atom. Here's a simplified example of what I have:

```
(ns my.app
  (:require
   [reagent.core :as r]
   [reagent-forms.core :as rf]))

(def appstate
  (r/atom {1 "a"
           2 "b"
           3 "c"}))

(defn inputfield
  ""
  [id]
  [:input {:field :text
           :id [id]}])

(defn inputfields
  ""
  []
  [:div
   (for [item @appstate]
     (inputfield (first item)))])

(defn total
  ""
  []
  [:div
   [rf/bind-fields (inputfields) appstate]
   [:div (str @appstate)]])

(r/render 
    [total]
    (js/document.getElementById "mainframe"))
```

This works insofar as changes to the input fields are reflected by the atom. **The shortcoming becomes evident once I evaluate the following:**

```
(swap! appstate #(assoc % 4 "d"))
```

While this does change the atom, no additional field is created in the DOM. It would seem the reason for this is my following the [reagent-forms documentation](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-forms#binding-the-form-to-a-document):

> The templates are eagerly evaluated, and you should always call the
>   helper functions as in the example above instead of putting them in a
>   vector. These will be replaced by Reagent components when the
>   bind-fields is called to compile the template.

As far as my understanding of reagent goes, this means that the atom in `inputfields` gets dereferenced when `bind-fields` is called . The returned components however no longer contain any reference of the atom, hence no re-rendering on atom-change.

Is there any way with reagent forms to get the forms-binding and the reactive creation and deletion of inputs I'm looking for?

Many thanks in advance

Oliver

Comment: I'm not as familiar with reagent-forms, but reading the documentation, I'm thinking this would probably be a limitation of how it's designed. Is there a specific reason you want to use that vs plain Reagent? At least your simplified example would be pretty easy, and would work as expected.

Comment: Sure. In fact this is exactly what I've been doing since the trouble with Reagent-forms has emerged – and plain Reagent is, of course, totally viable, even for the considerably more complex structure I'm actually dealing with (the one above is simplified a lot). 
The one reason why I'm still hoping to possibly make use of Reagent-forms is their date picker, which would come in handy… but I guess I'll find an alternative  for that as well… for now I'll leave this unsolved unless there's some official statement that hti si indeed impossible. Cheers!